# How to pass substring from Swift to C?

Tags: swift, interop

I have the variable with the value "7438754876*567".I have got this from string as substring.I want to pass this value to c function.

```
void getRechargePinFromDestination(char* rechargeNumber)
{
    setRechargeValue(rechargeNumber);
}
```

As I have declared as char, swift takes it as a Int8.How can I pass this value.Anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the C function *modify* the string? Or can you declare it as `void getRechargePinFromDestination(const char * rechargeNumber)` ?

Comment: Cannot convert value of type 'Substring' to expected argument type 'UnsafePointer<Int8>?' ........ This is my prblm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the C function does not mutate the passed string then you should declare the argument as a `const char*`:

```
void getRechargePinFromDestination(const char* rechargeNumber)
{
     // ...
}
```

Now you can pass Swift substrings by converting them to a `String` first (which is automatically converted to a temporary C string):

```
getRechargePinFromDestination(String(subString))
```

or with

```
subString.withCString { getRechargePinFromDestination($0) }
```

In either case, the C function is called with a pointer to a *temporary* C string representation, which is only valid during the function call.